# table granted to role holding another role but table does not found when selecting

Tags: sql, oracle, select, roles, sql-grant

I have a problem with the following situation in **Oracle** DBMS.

I have a students table **STUDENT** in **MAIN** schema, 1 user **USER_ADMIN** and 2 roles **ROLE_RW** and **ROLE_RW_ANY**.

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON MAIN.STUDENT TO ROLE_RW;

GRANT ROLE_RW TO ROLE_RW_ANY;

GRANT ROLE_RW_ANY TO USER_ADMIN;
```

But when USER_ADMIN executes this query:

```
SELECT * FROM MAIN.STUDENT;
```

It seems that the table is not accessible, that says `table does not exist`.

Do you have explanation and a solution please?

Many thanks.

Comment: probably there is an interference with other roles the user has been assigned too.

Comment: It's not enough to merely `GRANT` a role, you either need to `ALTER` the user to use it as the `DEFAULT ROLE` when logging on, or the user must activate the role for the session via `SET ROLE`.

Comment: @Fred, Which role I have to set as default for the user ROLE_RW or ROLE_RW_ANY?

Comment: The one granted to the user: ROLE_RW_ANY.